# How to use anacron with cron to perform missed tasks by cron?

Tags: scripts, python, cron, anacron

My python script needs to run at 2pm every day. Another python script must run at 9pm every day. To accomplish that I have set up 2 cronjobs to run those scripts at the given times:

```
0 14 * * * python /home/user/unban.py
0 21 * * * python /home/user/ban.py
```

For cron to run successfully my machine would have to run 24/7, I know that. How can I then use anacron to run the scripts in case the machine was offline when the cronjobs were scheduled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man anacrontab`:

> The period is specified in days, the delay in minutes.

Unfortunately, this means that anacron is inappropriate for determining a skipped *hourly* job.

Consider adding a bit more time-logic to your script and making it a single script:

```
// NOT REAL CODE. Just an example of the logic.
currently_banned = am_I_banned?()    
if 14 <= current_time().hour <= 21
    if currently_banned is True:
        unban()
    else:
        do_nothing()
else:
    if currently_banned is False:
        ban()
    else:
        do_nothing()
```

You can put the single script in cron.hourly, and can run the script at boot. Remember to add the script to your regular backup schema.

Alternately, you can trigger the job with a systemd timer/service combination, like all the other periodic services on your system. Systemd can also trigger the script at reboot, Systemd has a learning curve but I have found the learning to be very worthwhile.

Comment: I did some further research that day and also came to the conclusion that it would be better to handle the logic within the script. I think it's kind of sad for cron not being able to handle such a use-case. In my opinion its only downside.